# How to capture stdout stderr output of running process

Tags: logging, trace

I need to write a program that captures stdout/stderr output of other running processes on the same machine into a variable.
I would like to later transform those bytes into something else and do arbitrary things with it, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

My input is a list of PIDs, we can assume they're valid and that there's actually running processes with those PIDs. My target arch is Linux, but answers that also mention other hosts (like Windows) would be appreciated as well.

For each PID, every time the process with that PID writes into stdout or stderr, I want an event callback, that gives exactly the original bytes written by that process untransformed (note that if multiple messages got buffered, that's fine) into a variable that I can work with.

I don't care which programming language/environment the answer is for, as long as they're mainstream ones (C, C++, Go, Node.js, etc, are fine).

Similar questions on stack overflow recommend to run the tracked processes as a child process of the process that captures their stdout/stderr. This is not my use case. The PIDs run separately and cannot be spawned as a child process.

Other similar questions offer to use existing programs such as strace or gdb to get this done. I know how to do this and this is not what I want. Using a library for a programming language is fine, but I don't want to add a separate program dependency (dumping the entire source code of an existing open source program is out of the question too... unless they explicitly offer a lib version, i.e. like curl and libcurl).

I want an answer that describes, with any mainstream programming language, using a PID or list of PIDs as input, how to create event listeners to call a callback every time stdout or stderr was written into by process/es with those PID/s.

Note that if the PID process spawns subprocesses or is otherwise multithreaded, I want to be able to track stdout/stderr from its spawned threads as well.

I'm currently reading about sys/ptrace.h linux api for C because I assume that's the direction here, but if somebody already has an experience with this and knows the answer please share.

Comment: Yes, the Linux answer is to use `ptrace`. If you need examples, look at how `strace` is implemented.

Comment: @melpomene yeah that's what I'm doing right now, just thought maybe somebody already did something similar before and has a rundown on the key points that matter without all the error handling and corner cases around it